# Is there anyway to identify Asp.net identity token expiry timeout event or idle timeout event.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

We have created an **Identity server 4** application for **single sign-on** in Asp.net core 2.0. We use the Microsft Identity framework for login and account related pages.
The client applications are created using .net FW 4.7.1 in MVC 5 which are then connect to identity server for single sign-on purposes (used Identity server 3 in client application).

*We have a requirement wherein allow users to log in to the application only from a single device at a time. To achieve this, on user login, we create a unique LoginSessionId and store it in DB. On logout, we just make this session-id null.
If someone else tries to login with the same user on another device, we just check if the LoginSessionId has value. If yes, then we give a message informing the user that he's already logged in on another device and if he wants to kill the other session. If he says yes, we let him login and reset the LoginSessionId with a new one. As for the first device login, we have a check-in place to log out that user if his current LoginSessionId does not match the one in DB, so he gets logged out.
We have also set the AccessTokenLifetime and IdentityTokenLifetime of the identity server-client application to 24 hours. Here is the problem we're facing:
When the 24 hours are up after user login, the user gets logged out since the Token must have expired. But the LoginSessionId mentioned earlier is not reset. Thus when a user tries to log back in, we end up showing the message of another user logged in, which is not really the case*. Question is,

1. **Is there is any way to raise the token expiry event so that we can clear the LoginSessionId there?**
2. **Is there any common place where we can identify the various reasons due to which user gets logged out. Like was it due to token expiry, or because he was idle for a long time (sliding expiry I think), or if he clicked logout himself etc.**
3. **What is the max value that we can set for AccessTokenLifetime and IdentityTokenLifetime.**

Answer (score 0):

One needs to implement IEventService and IEventSink in  Identity Server 4 to get those evnts.

for more details, you can refer to this link.

[link](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/events.html)